# How to create separate arrays from a parent object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Suppose I have an object that looks like this

```
const parent_obj = {
  'metrics': [
    ['2023-03-28 15:40:00+00:00', 1692.1, 1.0],
    ['2023-02-28 15:40:00+00:00', 1211.6, 0.0],
    ['2023-01-28 15:40:00+00:00', 763.1, 1.0]
  ]
};
```

I want to have 2 arrays that look like this:

```
var duration = {
  'metrics': [
    ['2023-03-28 15:40:00+00:00', 1692.1],
    ['2023-02-28 15:40:00+00:00', 1211.6],
    ['2023-01-28 15:40:00+00:00', 763.1]
  ]
};
var error_ratio = {
  'metrics': [
    ['2023-03-28 15:40:00+00:00', 1.0],
    ['2023-02-28 15:40:00+00:00', 0.0],
    ['2023-01-28 15:40:00+00:00', 1.0]
  ]
};
```

I basically want to iterate through the metrics list and get index 0 and 1 for duration and 0 and 2 for error_ratio. What is the easiest way to accomplish this goal using vanilla javascript?

Comment: This would be easier to follow with a simplified data structure and better formatting.

Comment: Well, lets say from this: `['2023-03-28 15:40:00+00:00', 1692.1, 1.0]`, I want this: `['2023-03-28 15:40:00+00:00', 1692.1]` and this: `['2023-03-28 15:40:00+00:00', 1.0]`

Comment: Start with `parent_obj.metrics.forEach()`

Comment: I mean you can cut this down significantly, the times are just arbitrary data, so like `['A', 1.1, 2.2]` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is using the **`map method`**

```
const duration = {
  'metrics': parent_obj.metrics.map(metric => [metric[0], metric[1]])
};

const error_ratio = {
  'metrics': parent_obj.metrics.map(metric => [metric[0], metric[2]])
};
```

Comment: This seems like the most straightforward solution. I am doing this inside an Axios call several layers into a much larger object. I think this is the easiest to implement for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can define helper function that use `map` to get the data by index:

```js
const parent_obj = {
  'metrics': [
    ['2023-03-28 15:40:00+00:00', 1692.1, 1.0],
    ['2023-02-28 15:40:00+00:00', 1211.6, 0.0],
    ['2023-01-28 15:40:00+00:00', 763.1, 1.0],
  ],
};

const getMetrics = (data, indexes) => ({
  'metrics': data.metrics.map(entry => indexes.map(index => entry[index])),
});

const duration = getMetrics(parent_obj, [0, 1]);
const error_ratio = getMetrics(parent_obj, [0, 2]);

console.log(duration);
console.log(error_ratio);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take an helper array dor the groups and indices and map.

```js
const
    metrics = [['2023-03-28 15:40:00+00:00', 1692.1, 1.0], ['2023-02-28 15:40:00+00:00', 1211.6, 0.0], ['2023-01-28 15:40:00+00:00', 763.1, 1.0]],
    indices = [[0, 1], [0, 2]];
    duration = {},
    error_ratio = {};

[duration.metrics, error_ratio.metrics] = indices.map(ii => metrics.map(m => ii.map(i => m[i])));

console.log(duration);
console.log(error_ratio);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I like this; creative solution mapping the indices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript built-in `Array.reduce()` function like the one below. I think it will work for you.

```
let { duration, error_ratio } = parent_obj.metrics.reduce((data, item)=>{
    data.duration.push([item[0],item[1]])
    data.error_ratio.push([item[0],item[2]])
    return data
},{
    duration: [],
    error_ratio: []
})
```

More clarification about `Array.reduce()` visit this link https://www.programiz.com/javascript/library/array/reduce